# can i export excel data in 8"x11" and 11"x17" size format using python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is there any way we can render data into excel/spreadsheet similar to page size 8"x11" and 11"x17" format using python.

On python- xlsxwriter package, using worksheet.set_paper() we have the option to set the page size using pagesetup function, but this is not rendering the output in 8"x11" or 11"x17" format.

Requirement - Need to render account details from table to excel sheet. As this sheet has more columns, user has to scroll right to view entire data. In order to reduce scrolling, an option is provided in a UI pop up to view data either in page size 8"x11" and 11"x17" before rendering data into excel.

I know,through excel we can reduce the zoom size < 100, so that data can be viewed in single page. My question - is there any way we can reduce the size of cell data similar to 8"x11" and 11"x17" page layout without zoom effect in python?

Screenshot for reference
[image: Budget plan]

Comment: have you tried with Pandas . ?

Comment: @Harry_pb -No, i didn't tried

Comment: Try to import in pandas and it will work in tabular format. I am not sure if this will work for rendering

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to write to either Letter size or Tabloid size according to the [documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html#set_print_scale)

Your sizes correspond to the indices 1 & 3

Try:

`worksheet.set_paper(1)`

Or

`worksheet.set_paper(3)`

Update: If you are trying to render the image on to screen, that would not work. In which case, you would need to use `worksheet.set_zoom(<someIntegerVal>)`